# What this design pattern name (Loop through to call classes)

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

I have written classes. `Loader` class will call mulitple classes via foreach `$tasks`

Is there a name of this design pattern?

Loader

```
class Loader
{
    public function handle() 
    {
        $tasks = [
            DoSomethingFirst::class,
            DoSomethingSecond::class,
        ];

        foreach ($tasks as $task)
        {
            (new $task)->handle();
         }
    }
}
```

Called via Loader

```
class DoSomethingFirst
{
    public function handle() { //do something }
}

class DoSomethingSecond
{
    public function handle() { //do something }
}
```

Comment: Polymorphism... ?

Comment: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/108951/how-do-you-call-a-proxy-that-delegates-to-several-implementations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each `$task` is independent, you can think of your solution as an implementation of Command pattern.

As per [this](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/command), Command pattern helps solve the following problem:

> Need to issue requests to objects without knowing anything about the operation being requested or the receiver of the request.

So, in your use case, `Loader` creates request objects and isn't aware how these requests are internally executed.